# use dplyr mutate() inside for loop over multiple data frames

Tags: r

Beside other dplyr functions I like to use the dplyr mutate() function in a for loop over multiple dataframes.
I have a list with several dataframes. The goal is to manipulate each dataframe passing the for loop so that inside the loop the new dataframes can be used to get the aimed analysis.
Unfortunately I do not know how to do so. Any help would be so much appreciated!

Below I tried to create a reproducible example which illustrates what I am aiming to do. Please note, that the analysis inside the for loop would be extended if the wished datafiles can be created; but this further analysis is not needed to answer the problem.

So in the example we will first add a new variable to each datafile passing the loop which contains a time-value. Let say the first row is 30 seconds, every following row should be 30 seconds later.

Then we find teststart (first occurrence of value 5 in $P) and testend (second occurrence of value 5 in $P). Based on teststart and testend we reduce the datafile_wholemeasurement to the datafile_testduration.

In datafile_testduration we will then create a new variable testduration. testduration should can be calculated as the value in time_seconds_wholemeasurement minus the value of time_seconds_wholemeasurement at teststart.

Here the example and as far as it works:

```
d1 <- data.frame(P=c(1,5,2,3,4,7,5,6,7), E=c(4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(P=c(0,9,8,5,4,7,5), E=c(6,5,4,6,5,4,5))
d3 <- data.frame(P=c(6,5,4,6,5,4,6,5,4), E=c(3,2,1,5,5,5,5,5,5))
d4 <- data.frame(P=c(5,9,9,5,2,2,1,8,5,7,6,5),E=c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8))

file_contents <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4)

res <- data.frame(teststart = rep(NA,length(file_contents)), testend =rep(NA,length(file_contents)))


for(i in 1:length(file_contents))
{
  datafile_wholemeasurement <- file_contents[[i]] 
   
  teststart <- which(file_contents[[i]]$P == 5)[1]  
  testend <- which(file_contents[[i]]$P == 5)[2]    
  
  datafile_testduration <- file_contents[[i]] %>% 
    filter(between(row_number(), teststart, testend-1))
   
  res$teststart[[i]] <- teststart
  res$testend[[i]] <- testend
}
```

this is my attempt to do how described; it does not work:

```
for(i in 1:length(file_contents))
{
  datafile_wholemeasurement <- file_contents[[i]] %>%
    mutate(time_seconds_wholemeasurement = seq(from = 30, to = length(file_contents[[i]]$P)*30, by = 30))
  
  teststart <- which(file_contents[[i]]$P == 5)[1]  
  testend <- which(file_contents[[i]]$P == 5)[2]    
  
  datafile_testduration <- file_contents[[i]] %>% 
    filter(between(row_number(), teststart, testend-1)) %>%
    mutate(time_seconds_testduration = time_seconds_wholemeasurement - time_seconds_wholemeasurement[[1]]) 
  
  res$teststart[[i]] <- teststart
  res$testend[[i]] <- testend
}
```

Again, thanks for every support.

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly. However, he will try to help. But let us do it in R-style, without unnecessary `for` loops and keeping the topic as simple as possible. However, since this approach may be somewhat obscure for you, let me guide you through it step by step.

Let's start with data preparation in one `data frame` or rather `tibble` (better `data frame`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(
  d = paste0("d", 1:4),
  data = list(
    tibble(P=c(1,5,2,3,4,7,5,6,7), E=c(4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6)),
    tibble(P=c(0,9,8,5,4,7,5), E=c(6,5,4,6,5,4,5)),
    tibble(P=c(6,5,4,6,5,4,6,5,4), E=c(3,2,1,5,5,5,5,5,5)),
    tibble(P=c(5,9,9,5,2,2,1,8,5,7,6,5),E=c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8))
  )
)
df
```

output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  d     data             
  <chr> <list>           
1 d1    <tibble [9 x 4]> 
2 d2    <tibble [7 x 4]> 
3 d3    <tibble [9 x 4]> 
4 d4    <tibble [12 x 4]>
```

I know it can be a little confusing. But look at what is `df$data[[1]]`

```
data=df$data[[1]]
data
```

output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
      P     E
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4
2     5     5
3     2     6
4     3     4
5     4     5
6     7     6
7     5     4
8     6     5
9     7     6
```

As you can see, it's a `data frame` in a `data frame`.

Now let's do the first function that adds your measurement time to such a `data frame` in the `data frame`.

```
add_ts = function(data) data %>% mutate(tswm = seq(1, length(data$P))*30)
```

See how simple it can be. So let's test it.

```
add_ts(data) 
# A tibble: 9 x 3
      P     E  tswm
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    30
2     5     5    60
3     2     6    90
4     3     4   120
5     4     5   150
6     7     6   180
7     5     4   210
8     6     5   240
9     7     6   270
```

Did you expect it. I think so. So let's do a second function that adds test time. This one is just a tad more difficult.

```
add_tsd = function(data){
  tsdidx = (which(data$P==5)[1]):(which(data$P==5)[2]-1)
  data = data %>% mutate(tstd = NA)
  data$tstd[tsdidx]=seq(1,length(tsdidx))*30
  data
}
```

Let's test it right away

```
add_tsd(data)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
      P     E  tstd
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    NA
2     5     5    30
3     2     6    60
4     3     4    90
5     4     5   120
6     7     6   150
7     5     4    NA
8     6     5    NA
9     7     6    NA
```

Combine these two functions into one

```
add_ts_tsd = function(data) add_ts(data) %>% add_tsd()
add_ts_tsd(data)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
      P     E  tswm  tstd
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    30    NA
2     5     5    60    30
3     2     6    90    60
4     3     4   120    90
5     4     5   150   120
6     7     6   180   150
7     5     4   210    NA
8     6     5   240    NA
9     7     6   270    NA
```

We're doing fantastic. Well, let's do this now

```
df %>% mutate(data = map(data, add_ts_tsd)) 
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  d     data             
  <chr> <list>           
1 d1    <tibble [9 x 4]> 
2 d2    <tibble [7 x 4]> 
3 d3    <tibble [9 x 4]> 
4 d4    <tibble [12 x 4]>
```

Hmm, can't you see anything? Well, let's get these internal `data frame`.

```
df %>% mutate(data = map(data, add_ts_tsd)) %>% unnest(data)

# A tibble: 37 x 5
   d         P     E  tswm  tstd
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 d1        1     4    30    NA
 2 d1        5     5    60    30
 3 d1        2     6    90    60
 4 d1        3     4   120    90
 5 d1        4     5   150   120
 6 d1        7     6   180   150
 7 d1        5     4   210    NA
 8 d1        6     5   240    NA
 9 d1        7     6   270    NA
10 d2        0     6    30    NA
```

Bingo! Task completed. Simple and elegant. First of all, legibly.

Comment: There are no obstacles for you to further process the data prepared in this way! You can plot them, convert them and whatever else you want. Read Chapter 25 of *R for Data Science*  https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html carefully and you'll find that you don't really need `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks very much for the cleanly explained solution proposal @MarekFiolka. However, I am skeptical. Because creating this 2 mentioned dataframes would just be a first step in my thought for loop and further analyses (interpolations, creating and saving plots for each data set, etc.) should follow based on the new created dataframes. Moreover, in reality I will get ~100 datafile, not just four as in the example. Therefore, I thought of writing a for loop with which all datafiles stored in a certain folder can be evaluated. Am I wrong with a for loop or any recommendations?

Comment: I will read the proposed chapter @MarekFiolka. Thanks therefor. Do you also happen to know directly how i write the command to get all csv files stored in a certain folder into the data frame df you created?

Comment: Is this the best possible way to do?  

`setwd("~/workingdirectory")` 
`file_paths <- fs::dir_ls("myfolder")`
`file_contents <- list()`

`for (i in seq_along(file_paths)){
  file_contents[[i]] <- read.csv(
    file = file_paths[[i]], sep = ";")
}`

`file_contents <- setNames(file_contents, file_paths)`

`df = tibble(
  d = paste0(file_paths, 1:length(file_contents)),
  data = file_contents)`

Comment: Of course you can do that! 
1. Create functions will read all filenames in the selected directory and return as a vector. 
2. Save this vector as the first variable to tibble. 
3. Create a function eg `readFile` which will get the name of the file as a parameter and return `tibble` as output. 
4. Do `mutate (data = mapIfileName, readFile)`. 
5. Continue to process `tibble` in `tibble` as I showed you in the example.

Comment: I would like to thank you @MarekFiolka so much for answering my question in such a detailed and super understandable way. Beyond the fact that everything works, I (as a beginner in R) have learned a lot today while practicing with it, which is of enormous value for my work.